# my pendrive display in terminal sdb 8:16 1 14.5gb o disk, con't disply GUI mode and con't read and write

Tags: usb-drive, lsblk

I used the command `lsblk` and the system recognized my pendrive as `/dev/sdb`.

The problem is that I can't read or write to it.

Comment: Can you please be more explicit? Did you `mount` you USB drive?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) your usb in order to read and write data.

```
mkdir -p /media/$USER/usb
mount /dev/sdb1/ /media/$USER/usb
```

"Mounting" means "make a filesystem visible somewhere below `/`".